# Run a jquery without click function

Tags: php, jquery, function

I use expose in one link, with this code and it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var triggers = $("a[rel]").overlay({
    expose: {
      color: '#212121',
      loadSpeed: 200,
      opacity: 0.9
    },
    closeOnClick: false
  });
});
```

The link is:

```
<div id="triggers"><a href="" rel="#pop_member">Click here</a></div>
```

But I want to run the code printed in php so I change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function run_expire(){
    var triggers = $("#pop_member").overlay({
      expose: {
        color: '#212121',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
      },
      closeOnClick: false
    });
  }
});
```

and print in php:

```
echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">run_expire();</script>';
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `run_expire` function is only defined within the `document.ready()` function, so the code in your script tag can't find it.

There's no need to use `$(document).ready()` here.  A better solution would be simply this:

```
function run_expire(){
  var triggers = $("#pop_member").overlay({
    expose: {
        color: '#212121',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
    },
    closeOnClick: false
  });
}
```

You may want to make sure the document is ready before running `run_expire` though, which you can do like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">$(run_expire);</script>';
```

### Edit

Looking back at your code, there is another problem.  `$("#pop_member")` will not select a link defined this way:

```
<a href="" rel="#pop_member">
```

If you want the selector to work, you'd have to do this:

```
<a href="" id="pop_member">
```

However, this may not be what you want, because you can only have one element on a page with the same `id` attribute.  The `rel` attribute isn't really appropriate here, either.  You probably want to define it with a class, like this:

```
<a href="" class="pop_member">
```

with this selector:

```
$(".pop_member")
```

Alternatively, if you *really* want to select the link the way you have it written, you can use this selector:

```
$("a[rel='#pop_member']")
```

### Edit 3

Your real problem was stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452517/jquery-expose-overlay-function), which was that the jQuery tools library wasn't being used properly.  You need to pass `api: true` to the overlay function, and call `.load()` on the return value of the overlay function, in order for the overlay to be displayed programmatically on page load.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but did`t work yet, I need to expose that to happen without the need for a click but automatically when the page loads. The code that I put the link was just to show as an example of what I had.

Comment: @Mango:  this will make it call the run_expire function on page load: `<script type="text/JavaScript">$(run_expire);</script>`  You just have to make sure that run_expire is defined in global scope.

Comment: But in the code above it is global in scope, right?
It does not work, maybe jquery.tools.min.js  is to only work with links, I tried everything and not work.

Comment: I think the problem is on:
$("#red").overlay({
because work just a link whith:
  $("a[rel]").overlay({

Comment: @Mango: No, in *your* posted code, run_expire only exists inside of "`$(document).ready(function() { ... }`"

Comment: @Mango: What do you mean by `$("#red")` ?  You haven't mentioned that anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks Kip, #red is only a expample que name of the div, your example don`t help me because is it a link and I need the orverlay run without a link but when the page is load. Please take a look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452517/jquery-expose-overlay-function

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">$(function () { run_expire(); });</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

That's is because your `run_expire` function is defined inside the scope of the $(document).ready event handler.

You could define your function outside:

```
function run_expire(){
    var triggers = $("#pop_member").overlay({
        expose: {
            color: '#212121',
          loadSpeed: 200,
          opacity: 0.9
        },
        closeOnClick: false
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    run_expire();
});
```

That will define `run_expire` in the global scope, and your php generated script will work.