# Jquery expose overlay function

Tags: jquery, function, overlay

This function is not working, the popup (div #pop_member) doesn't show.

I'm using [jQuery Tools library](http://flowplayer.org/tools/).

```
function run_expire(){
  $("#pop_member").overlay({
    expose: {
        color: '#212121',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
    },
    closeOnClick: false
  });
}
run_expire();
```

I want this popup to show when the page is loaded:

```
<div class="simple_overlay" id="pop_member">
<div class="details">
  <h4>Member Admin Login Area</h4>
  <p>Sign in below to edit your personal and business information.</p>

  </div><!--details-->
</div><!--simple_overlay-->
```

Comment: Not working how? What specific plugin are you using? More info, don't make people guess.

Comment: Agreed with the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#pop_member").overlay({
    expose: {
        color: '#212121',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
    },
    closeOnClick: false,
    api: true  //ADDED api:true
  }).load();   //ADDED .load()
});
```

I got that from [the code here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/trigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

Does your page validate? Be sure it validates first because that fixes many issues.

Comment: The page is validate for sure, when a use this function open with a link work.